# How to publish Web Map on the internet?

Tags: arcims

I'm trying to use IIS 7 Manager to publish a web map on the internet except I have the folowing problem: [image]

I installed the ArcIMS web ADF for Java, and created a new webpage which depends on ArcIMS services (using ArcIMS admin), and then deployed it. When I opened the URL using another PC the page did not load.

To summarize, I have ArcIMS 9.3 (with servlet 5.0), ArcIMS web ADF for Java. What can i do to publish my web map ?

Comment: Have you installed the Web Management Role?

Comment: what is the web management role, i think (NO), i installed arcims, and create anew service and then create new web designer, only, and i want to publish this web map on the internet except my local pc.

Answer (score 4):

A. Navigate to Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features.

B. Click 'Turn Windows features on or off' on the left.

C. Click 'Features' on the left.

D. Click 'Add Features' on the right.

E. Expand 'Remote Server Administration Tools,' expand 'Role Administration Tools,' and place a check beside 'Web Server (IIS) Tools.' Click Next.

F. Click Install.

G. Once complete, click Roles on the left.

H. Click 'Add Roles' on the right.

I. Click Next, place a check beside Web Server (IIS) and click Next twice.

K. In the Role Services window, place checks beside 'ISAPI Extensions,' 'ISAPI Filters' and 'ASP' under Web Server > Application Development and beside 'IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility' under Management Tools > **IIS 6 Management Compatibility.** Click Next.

L. Click Install.

M. Once complete, **restart IIS by clicking Start and typing IISRESET in the search box, or go to Administrative Tools > Services and restart the IIS Admin Service and World Wide Web Publishing Service.**

N. Open the IIS Manager by navigating to Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

O. Expand the server host name, and Sites on the left. Select the Default Web Site.

P. In the middle of the window, right-click on **MIME Types** and select Open Feature.

Q. Click Add from the Actions panel on the right to open the Add Mime Type dialog box.

**Enter 'axl' in the File name extension field. Enter 'text/xml**' in the Mime Type field. Click OK.

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35515

Comment: Back again, i followed the same steps in the ESRI article, but i have a problem in step 8 to test iis and tomact, 'Hello World' is not test successful.(http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=35515)